# Lightning Component as Quick Action not showing beside the buttons

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I created a lightning component and a quick action that points to that component.
Now I dragged that button in the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section and it does not show up at the top inline with the other button.
It shows up as a tab instead.

Anyone knows why? or is there something i did wrong or missed?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is a expected behaviour from salesforce when feed tracking is
>   enabled for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those
>   records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons.
>   Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

**workaround:-**

So in order to not see the action in the feed on Case or Work orders object record, you need to disable the feed tracking for your case object.

Steps are:- setup--> feed tracking--> select case--> disable it and save

Reference:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0

Hope it helps you.