# Lightning Component as a button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I have created a lightning component that opens as a popup which requires some input from the user using based on which he is redirected to an external link. All of this functionality works correctly and the lightning component is a quick action. But the issue is that the quick action gets added to the Chatter feed of that particular record.

Is there any way that this remains as a button. The chatter feed shows the page when we click on the feed. I have added the lightning component as a button but still has no effect. How can I disable it to be shown on chatter feed and instead show up as a button?

The case detail page has the button listed under "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions". The lightning component itself implements the below:

```
implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableforallpagetypes"
```

Apart from this, with respect to the UI, I can see that there is a question raised exactly similar to this.

[Lightning Component as Quick Action not showing beside the buttons](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224577/lightning-component-as-quick-action-not-showing-beside-the-buttons)

I do not see any solution provided to this question either. But I have a similar problem and the button in my scenario is also added to the case details page layout. It would be great to solve this nagging issue.

If there is an easy alternative to invoke this component through a regular button using a JS, that would also help a lot.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you put a screenshot of your problem.  quick action gets added to the Chatter feed of that particular record in which UI? classic or lightning?

Comment: Quick actions on the Case object do not show in the highlights panel in Lightning: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/162608/12645

Comment: @sanketkumar, please have a look in the link in the textual description. It shows an image from another question. Basically, the same problem. And it is in lightning.

Comment: @JohnTowers, thanks for that link. It looks like the same problem that I have. The target organization does have chatter feed. We did not have that in our test environments. It looks really bad. There does not seem to be a workaround for this is it?

Comment: I'm not aware of a workaround. The best I've been able to do is put the component on the case record page in a location that makes sense for my users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is a expected behaviour from salesforce when feed tracking is
>   enabled for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those
>   records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons.
>   Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

**workaround:-**

> So in order to not see the action in the feed on Case or Work orders
>   object record, you need to disable the feed tracking for your case
>   object.

Steps are

```
setup > feed tracking  > select case > disable it and save
```

Reference

- [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5)

**Alternate option:-**

> You can create a visualforce page which does the same functionality as
>   your Lightning component and creates a visualforce page button and
>   then add it to the layout. It will give what you want without caring
>   the feed tracking is enabled or not.

Comment: I know this, but the client organization needs it. Unfortunately, cannot do it.

Comment: @Adarsh I have updated my answer, you can try it. but the only thing is it will not open as a popup.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternate options:

1) Create a Lightning Component that looks like a button, and place it somewhere else on the page layout using App Builder. Clicking the button would launch the desired behaviour.

2) Create a Lightning Component that implements `lightning:isUrlAddressable` and create a link button that navigates to that component's Lightning URL, passing enough parameters to have the info you need (record ID for example). This will show full-screen rather than as a modal. Also note that the component will have to handle changes to `v.pageReference` to ensure it behaves correctly if a user navigates to it a second time in the same session.

Comment: I quite like the 1st approach you have mentioned. We have added our lightning component on the page. But this shows up on the sections with the page. What do you mean by "create a component that looks like a button"?

Comment: I mean create a Lightning component where the markup is just a button (e.g. `lightning:button`). On click of that Lightning component it could toss up a modal window (e.g. using `lightning:overlayLibrary`) that displays the actual pop-up you want.